# Fingerprinting PHP files

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess, caching

While linking to web page assets like JS, image or CSS files you can append "`?v=$timestamp or random number`" to ensure the server loads the latest version of the file, but while doing "`require_once`" or "`include_once`" in PHP appending "`?v=$timestamp or random number`" throws a  warning `failed to open stream`.

My question is how can I achieve the same feature while including PHP files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The timestamp trick is used where a browser might be caching files to ensure that the current version is loaded.

`include` and `require` are generally used to load files from the local file system which is not cached, so there should be no need to fingerprint them.

If you're loading PHP libraries remotely, (e.g. `include('http://www.example.com/someLibrary.php')`) there's no browser to cache it so same should generally apply, but the fingerprint should work anyway to defeat any proxy caching that might get in the way.

Comment: But there is the added complication if you are using opcache that it *may* be configured to use the in-memory compiled code and rarely or never check the underlying file - https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php - this behaviour should not be manipulated from inside your code.

Comment: @symcbean I tried disabling `ini_set('opcache.enable', '0');` but the code keeps loading memory compiled code, so I renamed the files to serve updated version but that doesn't solve the actual problem.

Comment: "this behaviour should not be manipulated from inside your code". And switching off opcache is a really bad idea. In your php.ini file set opcache.revalidate_freq to 0 and opcache.validate_timestamps to 1

Comment: @symcbean Tried this and the problem still persist

Comment: 1) you never said what the problem was. 2) you need to do more than just change the config files.